# ReplacementSpan's draw() method isn't called

Tags: android, spannablestring

I set background in string like that:

```
spanString.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(color), 0, 3, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

But I would like to increase left and right padding in this background so I created custom span

```
public class PaddingBackgroundSpan extends ReplacementSpan {
private int mBackgroundColor;
private int mForegroundColor;

public PaddingBackgroundSpan(int backgroundColor, int foregroundColor) {
    this.mBackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    this.mForegroundColor = foregroundColor;
}

@Override
public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
    return Math.round(measureText(paint, text, start, end));

}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {
    RectF rect = new RectF(x, top, x + measureText(paint, text, start, end), bottom);
    paint.setColor(mBackgroundColor);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
    paint.setColor(mForegroundColor);
    canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x, y, paint);
}

private float measureText(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end) {
    return paint.measureText(text, start, end);
}
```

I use my span by:

```
spanString.setSpan(new PaddingBackgroundSpan(color1, color2), 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Unfortunately, my draw() method isn't called. getSize() is called correctly.

Answer (score 27):

In case anyone has this problem, I encountered it. What I had to do is to pass a second parameter into the setText() method. My call looked like

```
textView.setText(spanned, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 11):

The documentation for [ReplacementSpan.getSize()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ReplacementSpan#getSize(android.graphics.Paint,%2520java.lang.CharSequence,%2520int,%2520int,%2520android.graphics.Paint.FontMetricsInt)) provides the answer:

> Returns the width of the span. Extending classes can set the height of the span by updating attributes of Paint.FontMetricsInt. **If the span covers the whole text, and the height is not set, draw() will not be called for the span**.

Make sure to update `Paint.FontMetricsInt` with proper values to fix the problem.

In my case, I just took the metrics from the `TextView`'s `Paint`:

```java
@Override
public int getSize(
        Paint paint,
        CharSequence text,
        int start,
        int end,
        Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
    final Paint.FontMetrics paintFontMetrics = paint.getFontMetrics();
    if (fm != null) {
        fm.ascent = (int) paintFontMetrics.ascent;
        fm.bottom = (int) paintFontMetrics.bottom;
        fm.descent = (int) paintFontMetrics.descent;
        fm.leading = (int) paintFontMetrics.leading;
        fm.top = (int) paintFontMetrics.top;
    }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In method `getSize()` the `Paint.FontMetricsInt fm` must be recalculated based on `paint` FontMetricsInt:

```
@Override
public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
    width = Math.round(paint.measureText(text, start, end));
    Paint.FontMetricsInt metrics = paint.getFontMetricsInt();
    if (fm != null) {
        fm.top = metrics.top;
        fm.ascent = metrics.ascent;
        fm.descent = metrics.descent;

        fm.bottom = metrics.bottom;
    }
    return width;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like I found a working (but hacky) solution to this problem. Try to add another symbol to the end of the string so that it isn't included in the span - and then `draw()` gets called!

```
 char EXTRA_SPACE = ' ';
 String text = originalString + EXTRA_SPACE;
 Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(text);
 spannable.setSpan(new MyReplacementSpan(), 0, text.length()-1, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 textView.setText(spannable);
```

Looks like it ignores the spans which are whole string wide.

Comment: Indeed, it works but why should we need a workaround like that seriously..

Answer (score 3):

Even if you return the width of the span, the height of the span is 0 when the span covers the whole string. Therefore your span is actually there, with the specified width but the height is 0, therefore not drawn.

You have to set the height of the span updating the values of the parameter *Paint.FontMetricsInt fm* for function *getSize*. Check the [DynamicDrawable.getSize](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/style/DynamicDrawableSpan.java#74) function as a reference to set the height by updating the FontMetrics values.

Answer (score 0):

Call that view's `invalidate()` method in order to force invoke on `draw()`.

Comment: I don't want to make mess on view level, I want Span that make padding on its own like with standard BackgroundColorSpan. Is it possible? [EDIT] I have just checked Your solution. Call invalidate on TextView after add SpannableString (is it Your proposition?) and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it helps to you. Set textView width match parent.
main_activity.xml

```
<TextView
   android:width="match_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

This method can refresh the aync load ImageSpan

```kotlin
        try {
            val sendWatchersMethod =
                SpannableStringBuilder::class.java.getDeclaredMethod("sendToSpanWatchers", Int::class.java, Int::class.java, Int::class.java)
            sendWatchersMethod.isAccessible = true
            val len = length()
            sendWatchersMethod.invoke(spanString, 0, len, len)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```