# Custom text span not working

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

I am trying to create a span to give a rounded background to text. However, the `draw` method is never called.

This is the code:

```
public class RoundedBackgroundSpan extends ReplacementSpan {

    @Override
    public  void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint)
    {
        RectF rect = new RectF(x, top, x + measureText(paint, text, start, end), bottom);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, 100f, 30f, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x, y, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public  int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm)
    {
        return Math.round(measureText(paint, text, start, end));
    }

    private float measureText(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end)
    {
        return paint.measureText(text, start, end);
    }
}
```

And this is how I am setting it up:

```
 Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(introText.getText());
 spannable.setSpan(new RoundedBackgroundSpan(), 0, textView.getText().length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 textView.setText(spannable);
```

I don't have a clue of why this is not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069537/replacementspans-draw-method-isnt-called may give you some clues. I haven't used a custom subclass of `ReplacementSpan` yet.

Comment: the answer suggests to add a second parameter to setText so that it becomes textView.setText(spanned, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);, but for me this is not working yet. The getSize method is called though

Comment: I found a hack that makes it work, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32170735/258848

Answer (score 0):

Create shapes.xml like the following

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
    <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp" />
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

In your xml file, use android:background="@drawable/shapes" for the text.

Comment: But this will not work if I only want to add the round corner background to a substring, not the whole string.